# How to Apply color to Excel cell data(to particular characters) using c#?

Tags: c#

I am Exporting a jquery grid data to Excel, for this i am preparing a table at run time with data from grid and inserting html elements with inline styles to get colored text.
this is working for word and PDF  but not for excel cell.
I want to show color for some particular characters in a cell. how to do that?

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Hi Yahia, i was not aware now i am getting ...Thank you for your advice. Actually  I am Preparing a table with exporting data contains inserted Html elements to style the chars in a cell(not entire cell) at run time both for word & Excel, it is giving styles for word but not for excel.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put multiple `<Data>` with different `ss:Color` attributes inside one `<Cell>` although I am not sure that "Excel-HTML" even supports what you want.

For some in-depth information regarding the HTML approach to creating Excel files with sample code see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx

Also checkout the official documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx

Other options to create Excel files (which AFAIK support what you want):

MS provides the OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel).

Another option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx

IF you need more like rendering, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.